# Want to make a dynamic grid in bootstrap slider in php

Tags: php, mysql, twitter-bootstrap

I have made a dynamic bootstrap slider according the data fetched from database in php. Here I want to display 3 grid per slider, it works completely. But I just want to create a 3 grid in a single row. Here i got the grid in new row. What I have to do to get the 3 grid in a single row?

```
<div class="container content">
    <div id="carousel-example-generic" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel"> 
        <ol class="carousel-indicators"> 
            <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li> 
            <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="1"></li>
        </ol> 
        <div class="col-lg-12">
            <h1><center>Client Reviews</center></h1>
        </div>
        <div class="carousel-inner">
        <?php
        foreach($hello as $review){

 ?>
<?php if ($i % 3 == 0):?>
    <div class="item<?php if ($is_active) echo ' active'?>">
<?php endif?>


        <div class="row"> 
            <div class="col-xs-12" style="margin:35px;"> 
                <div class="col-md-4"> 
                            <div class="caption"> 
                                <p class="text-info lead adjust2"><?php echo $review\['testimonial'\];?></p> 
                                <p><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-minus"></span> <?php echo $review\['name'\];?></p> 
                            </div>
                    </div> 
                </div> 
            </div>


            <?php if (($i+1) % 3 == 0 || $i == count($review)-1):?>
    </div>

            <?php endif?>
<?php
$i++;
if ($is_active) $is_active = false;
        };
?>
        <a class="left carousel-control" href="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide="prev"> 
         <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span> </a>
        <a class="right carousel-control" href="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide="next"> 
         <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span> </a>
    </div>
 </div>
```

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Any solution for these problem help me

Answer (score 0):

I think u open   add before loop.

```
    [![<div class="container content">
    <div id="carousel-example-generic" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
         <ol class="carousel-indicators">
             <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
             <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="1"></li>
        </ol>
            <div class="col-lg-12">
                <h1><center>Client Reviews</center></h1>
            </div>
        <div class="carousel-inner">
          <div class="row">
              <div class="col-xs-12" style="margin:35px;">
        <?php
        foreach($hello as $review){

 ?>
 <?php if ($i % 3 == 0):?>
    <div class="item<?php if ($is_active) echo ' active'?>">
<?php endif?>



                        <div class="col-md-4">
                                    <div class="caption">
                                        <p class="text-info lead adjust2"><?php echo $review\['testimonial'\];?></p>
                                        <p><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-minus"></span> <?php echo $review\['name'\];?></p>
                                    </div>
                            </div>



                <?php if (($i+1) % 3 == 0 || $i == count($review)-1):?>
    </div>

            <?php endif?>
<?php
$i++;
if ($is_active) $is_active = false;
        };
?>
                 <a class="left carousel-control" href="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide="prev">
                 <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span> </a>
                 <a class="right carousel-control" href="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide="next">
                 <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span> </a>
               </div>
           </div>
 </div>
 </div>][1]][1]
```

Comment: These work but i  want to create 3 grid in each slider in these code i get all the grids fetched from database